# Can two cuboids with different side lengths have the same volume and perimeter?

Tags: general-topology, algebra-precalculus, geometry

We know that two rectangles with different side lengths cannot have the same area provided their perimeter is the same. But two cuboids with different side lengths can (as evidenced by the example 1,6,6; 2,2,9 in an answer below) have the same volume and perimeter. Side lengths are constrained to be integers.

I have glossed over it a bit; but can't seem to find a proof.

Comment: By perimeter do you mean total length of all edges?

Comment: @Travis ....yes

Comment: The answer is false. Here is a counter example,

let $2,4,6$ be the side lengths of the $1^{st}$ cuboid, Now, let $2,2,12$ be the side lengths of the $2^{nd}$ cuboid.

These two have the same volume, even though they have different side lengths.

Comment: @alkabary Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can generalize paw88789's example. For all $n>1$ the formula $(1,2n^2-n,2n^2-n)$ and $(n,n,(2n-1)^2)$ produces two different cuboids that have the same total edge length and volume.

I can also show why this can be done in three dimensions and not two. Let $l$ be the rectangle's length. Let $w$ be the rectangle's width. Let $P$ be a known value the rectangle's perimeter. Let $A$ be another known value the rectangle's Area. Therefore the two following formulas describe the rectangle. $2l+2w=P$ and $lw=A$ There are two equations and two unknowns therefore rectangles can be uniquely identified by their perimeter and area. Applying the same procedure for the cuboids, let $h$ be the height of the cuboid. We get two formulas $4l+4w+4h=P$ and $lwh=A$. This is two equations and three unknowns, so knowing a cuboid's total edge length and volume doesn't uniquely identify the cuboid. It then becomes possible to construct two different cuboids with the same total edge length and volume.

Answer (score 3):

How about $1, 6, 6$ and $2, 2, 9$?

Comment: Exactly, Same volume and perimeter but different side lengths

Comment: That's a nice example but how do we prove it in general?

Comment: @Soham: The example gives the proof (of existence), which I gather was the point of the question.  By the way: Here's another example with all side lengths for each cuboid different: $1, 12, 14$ and $2, 4, 21$.

Comment: hm..now we know its possible, but a general proof would build understanding as to why its possible with cuboids but not with rectangles

Comment: @Soham: Are you perhaps looking for a formula/algorithm to produce many (or even all possible) examples?

Comment: That'd be nicer still. Here's an analogy which conveys my thought. Producing pythagorean triples and proving pythagorean theorem are two different things even though the former is a proof (of the existence of such triples)